# Register asp.net in IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, iis, nettcpbinding

I have one issue which is related with registering asp.net in IIS 10.
My environment is Windows 10, IIS 10, VS 2013 and VS 2015 installed, .NET 3.5 is a feature in Windows Features.
I want to use nettcpbinding in IIS, so, I installed WCF HTTP activation and WCF Non-HTTP Activation. After it, I will need to re-register asp.net in IIS. I run below command

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i
```

And I got below result, is asp.net registered correctly in IIS?
Any help would be appreciated.

> Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0
>
> Administration
> utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Start
> installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).
>
> This option is not supported on this
> version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead
> install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows
> Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the
> dism.exe command line tool.  For more details please see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.
>
> Finished installing
> ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).

Comment: It clearly says "Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5..."

Comment: thanks, if you mean run as administrator, I have used. And eventually, I tried this command "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45", it works.

Comment: Then what's the remaining issue?

Comment: No, my issue has been resolved. Thanks

Comment: Post what you did in an answer, and then accept it. That's how we close questions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For this issue, I resolved by below command to install asp.net in IIS.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45
```

Comment: I had to run it as admin, and include /all

Comment: adding the /all worked for me too. Don't forget to close IIS Manager and open it up again.

Comment: Thank you for this. My configuration is IIS 10, Win 10, VS 2017 ( Community edition ) and having hard-time with .asmx. I had to run this :

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>dism /online /enable-feature /all  /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!  So dumb that installing Web Server components through Control Panel doesn't automatically "activate" or have a prompt at the end of installation asking "Now that it is installed, would like to make it usable in IIS?"