# MVC Shows Directory Listing Not Loading Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-10, iis-10

I have a project that for some reason isn't loading the project, but just is showing me the directory listings. I have even tried running it in local IIS to see if it makes a difference and it doesn't

Things I have tried

1. modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"
2. remove and reinstall IIS from manage windows applications in control panel

If I create a template MVC project in visual studio and run it , it runs fine so that makes me think its not my configruation. Other uses with the same project and web config are having no problem getting the site to load.

Also if I try and goto /Home/Index I get a 404 error. Not sure if that helps in any way

Any other ideas I may be missing here

IIS 10 on Windows 10

Comment: mmm, where that project came from?

Comment: Its a custom in house project

Comment: In File Explorer: right click on the folder, go to properties, uncheck read-only, click on Security tab, make sure the folder has all permissions required to run IIS.

Comment: @derloopkat , I think because of git my folders are locked down on read only, but I have checked security on the folder where my project lives and set all users to full control and still the same thing.

If i add an index.html to the root it will load that file no problem but thats not what im looking for

Comment: @derloopkat the from scratch application worked in express but in local IIS i was getting permissions errors.

Comment: That makes more sense. Make sure IIS is enabled in Windows Features and Asp.net is registered, because when it isn't this is exact result.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check that [IIS is installed](https://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/) and features you require are enabled
2. [Register Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659281/register-asp-net-in-iis-10) in Windows 10 for the Framework version you use.

   > dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45
3. [Remove read-only tick](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-read-only-files-folders-54559.html) and [grant IIS with permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934006/iis-iusrs-and-iusr-permissions-in-iis8) on the folder your application is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go over your IIS configurations again, do re-check whether you have the “Default Document” set for your website in IIS Manager.

Also, if you’re running directly via Visual Studio, check whether you have selected the relevant “Project” as the “Startup Project” for the Solution (visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx).

If the above fail, do recheck the IIS Permission for the particular project (visit https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313075/how-to-configure-web-server-permissions-for-web-content-in-iis)

Lastly as mentioned above, do un-check the "Read Only" Flag if its there. 
Do share your feedback and let me know if your problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit too late but just check if you have these features turned on:

[image]

After checking and installing ASP.NET 4.8, IIS should be able to load your Home/Index page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

install mvc application with this command

`install-windowsfeature web-asp-net45`

or install ASP.Net 4  in role server
[Detail](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Windows_Server_2019&p=iis&f=7)